# Tables using Perl CGI.pm

Tags: perl, html-table, cgi

I am trying to create a table using CGI.pm. The table would contain results from
querying a database. The array final contains record numbers on which the queries will
be executed. The results for each record should be in a separate row. The result 
of each query on the record should form a column in the row. Using some code I found 
[here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.59/cgi_docs.html), I wrote the following
(which may not be he best way of doing it):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use DBI;

...

my @rows;
my $rec;

foreach my $el (@final) {
              @rows = ();
    foreach my $query (@queries) {
        my $query_handle = $connxn->prepare($query);
        $query_handle->execute($el);
        $query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$rec);
        while($query_handle->fetch()) {
            push(@rows,td($rec));
        }   
    }
    print $q->table({-border=>undef,-width=>'25%'},
        Tr(\@rows)
       );
}
```

When I run this, I get a blank page and an error "Undefined subroutine &main::td"
in the error log. Why do I get this error and I how do I get rid of it? Is there any 
other way to create a table the table I want using CGI.pm? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Using Sinan's suggestion, I modified my code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use DBI;  
use Carp; 
use HTML::Template;

...  
my @rows; 
my $rec;  
foreach my $el (@final) {     
    foreach my $query (@queries) {         
        my $query_handle = $connxn->prepare($query);         
        $query_handle->execute($el);         
        $query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$rec);         
        while($query_handle->fetch()) {             
            push(@rows, { CELLS => [ map { CELL => $_ }, $rec ] });         
        }        
    } 
}

my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new(filehandle => \*DATA);
$tmpl->param(ROWS => \@rows); 
print $tmpl->output;

__DATA__ 
<table> 
<TMPL_LOOP ROWS> 
<tr> 
<TMPL_LOOP CELLS> 
<td><TMPL_VAR CELL></td> 
</TMPL_LOOP>
</tr> 
</TMPL_LOOP>
</table>
```

But now I am getting the result of each query in a separate row, instead of the same one
(see original question above). I can't seem to fix it on my own. Any ideas?

EDIT2: Though I am accepting Sinan's answer, meanwhile I developed my own solution (in case anyone is interested):

```
my @rows;
my @rows1;
foreach my $el (@final) {
    @rows = ();
    foreach my $query1 (@queries) {
        my $query_handle = $connxn->prepare($query1);
        $query_handle->execute($el);
        $query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$rec);
        while($query_handle->fetch()) {
            push(@rows, $rec);              
        }                       
    }
    push(@rows1, { CELLS => [ map { CELL => $_ }, @rows ] }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you think you want to use [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI) to generate the tables, but you shouldn't. The code will be ugly and it will hurt.

Instead, separate presentation from logic. Avoid the HTML generation functions of `CGI.pm`. Use a simple templating module such as [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTemplate). Customize the HTML to your heart's content without messing with your code.

Given the update to your question, I think what you need is this:

```
foreach my $el (@final) {
    my @cells;
    foreach my $query (@queries) {         
        my $query_handle = $connxn->prepare($query);         
        $query_handle->execute($el);         
        $query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$rec);
        while($query_handle->fetch()) {
            push @cells, { CELL => $rec };
        }        
    } 
    push @rows, { CELLS => \@cells };
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I cannot figure out how to use it in my case. Should I store my results in some data structure that I pass to this function? Please help me on this.

Comment: I am not sure if you have seen my update, but I think it answers your question.

Comment: I simply copy-pasted your commands, and the first one gives me an error `Not enough arguments for map, near "} @"`. Also says `syntax error near "} @`. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I forgot a comma. Assuming `$rec` is an array ref to a row retrieved from the database, that should work.

Comment: Right, but each query here retrieves only a single element of the database (usually a string), not a whole row. I fixed this by removing the @ in front of $rec. But now there is another problem. Pease see my edited question.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Sorry I did not see your solution earlier as I was working on my own (see the edit). But I am accepting your answer as it is correct and does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Try using "`use CGI qw(:standard);`" instead of "`use CGI;`". Otherwise the Namespace of the CGI-Module is not imported.

The other way is using "`push(@rows,CGI->td($rec))`" instead of "`td()`".

This is also applicable on the `tr(\@rows)`

Here's the full working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use DBI;

...

my @rows;
my $rec;

foreach my $el (@final) {
    foreach my $query (@queries) {
        my $query_handle = $connxn->prepare($query);
        $query_handle->execute($el);
        $query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$rec);
        while($query_handle->fetch()) {
            push(@rows,td($rec));
        }   
    }
    print table({-border=>undef,-width=>'25%'},
        tr(\@rows)
       );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now at least I can see the tables! But using `push(@rows,td($rec));` still gives me each result in a new line, instead of a new row. How do I fix that?

Comment: Lines == Rows ! Or do you mean columns ?

Comment: Oops, I meant `each result in a new line, instead of a new column`. Sorry

Comment: Remove the "\" in Front of @rows -- but Sinan is right: You should use plain HTML, which is divided from the logic. It's more clean... Anyway, if you still want to use CGI, this should work

Comment: +1 Thanks again. It works now, but yeah Sinan's suggestion seems to be better